# Layered navigation internal working

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-community

please let me know

how attribute associate with layered navigation?

And if an **attribute** is assigned to only **associated product**, while that product has visibility is `not visible individually`.
it's **parent configurable product** is **showing** in listing, as well as product count is correct for that **attribute** options why?

`How those options are being related to configurable product?` I can't find any documentation for this.

I am just curious to know its internal working.

Comment: Even i am looking for same answer if u have found it till now please do send me the link